# Template for class objects

Tags: c++, class, templates, initialization

I wrote a class, which looks as follows:

```
template <typename Function, class RNG>
class Langevin{
public:
   Langevin(RNG & gen_, Function & force_, vector & qp_)
   : gen(gen_),force(force_),qp(qp_){}

    void ABO(const int T){
        for(int t=0; t<T;++t){
            ABO_step();
        }
    }

private: 
void ABO_step(){...}

vector & qp;
RNG & gen;
Function & force;
};
```

and built a class-object and called the member function:

```
int main(){
... 
vector qp_sl;
qp_sl.reserve(T+1);
qp_sl.push_back({0.0,0.1});
auto harmonic_force=[](double q){return -q;};
Langevin<decltype(harmonic_force), std::default_random_engine> sl_scheme(gen,harmonic_force, qp_sl);
sl_scheme.ABO(T);
```

Now i got the error messages:

`‘Langevin<main()::<lambda(double, double)>, std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul> >::force’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
 Function & force;`

I am overstrained, what is the mistake?

Comment: Thats a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is trying to tell you that the data member `force` will be initialized after `qp` even it appears before `qp` in the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order).

Note that the data members are always initialized in the order of their declaration.

> Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.

You should make them the same to avoid such kind of confusing.

```
Langevin(RNG & gen_, Function & force_, vector & qp_)
: qp(qp_), gen(gen_), force(force_) {}
```